# Tagging individual files from multiple directories in Subversion

Tags: svn, tags, copy

I have a repository composed of separate directories for different components of a system like this:

```
System
 - branches
 - tags
 - trunk
     Component A
       file A
       file B
     Component B
       file C
       file D
     Component C
       file E
       file F
```

Let's say I make some changes to file A and file C and file E and I want to create a tag of those files to mark them as the released versions.  How do I do that?  I'm pretty sure Subversion only allows the creation of a tag of an entire directory.  Can I manually create a subdirectory under tags and do individual Subversion copies of the files into the subdirectory to end up with the following?:

```
System
  - branches
  - tags
      Release-06-30-2010
        file A
        file C
        file E
  - trunk
    ...
```

I want to retain the log history of the files A, C, and E.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a separate repo for each component. Then you can use `svn:externals` to bring them into your *system*, and you can reference the repo with a specific revision number so you can lock it down.

When you commit your *system*, the URLs used for the `svn:externals` references will be saved (along with the specific revision number, if used), so when you check out different revisions or branches of *system*, you will get the correct revision of your components as well.